# How do I convert characters to numbers (where there are actually numbers) in R?

Tags: r, readxl, writexl

When importing data using readxl into R (i don't have the other version requiring java as it won't install), using col_names = false, the data will import as characters instead of numbers - which means I can't actually do any functions on them. Similarly, using writexl when creating a table, making col_names = false also turns numbers into text. I can't seem to find a workaround for this (I can't seem to find a function where I can create custom column names so I tried converting the characters into numbers using:

`databook[] <- lapply(databook, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

this worked, however the row that had the specific column titles I wanted (which were letters only) disappeared. I had to import the table using col_names = FALSE because colmn 2 onwards all have the same title and so when r imports it they rename the column titles which I don't want.
I tried specifying a particular set of rows on which to run the changes:

`databook[2:13,] <- lapply(databook, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

However, this caused it to no longer convert the characters (using `str(databook)` returned chr results instead of num). Furthermore, a random empty row was added in row 2, giving me 14 rows when the original table had 13.

I'd be grateful for any help fixing this.

Comment: You are better off importing with `col_names=TRUE`, but setting `.name_repair="minimal"` as this won't change your column names at all.  

Or skip the first row (`skip=1`) when you're reading the data then add your own column names later.

Comment: No worries.  Its a good idea to read all of the documentation when you use a new function for the first time so you can find things like this.